# Obtain the Actual Left,Top position of a rotated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I have a div that is rotated 45 degrees and its attributes are: left: 0, top: 0, width: 100px, height: 100px. **Can I obtain the actual x,y position of the divs top left corner?**

When the div is rotated, the top left corner sits at about -10px,-10px(guess). But I am attempting to calculate the actual top left corners x,y position for a web application.

*Maybe you know of a mathematical formula that can determine the top left corners x,y position? Or maybe a javascript attribute will give me it?* Such as div.style.actualLeft;?

Comment: @jacktheripper yes always a square

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is static 45 degrees and the origin of the rotation is in the center then you'll only have to calculate this once which is:

```
sqrt((width/2)^2+(height/2)^2)
sqrt(50^2+50^2) // Pythagorean theorem
```

which is **70,71067811865475**

So compared to the origin,  x wise it's negative 70,7106... and y wise it's 0.

If you are going to rotate it dynamicly so you must know it all the time then voila! Behold!

compute the distance once, `sqrt(50^2+50^2)`, then multiply this by the rotation you're adding to the cube + 135 degrees (cause it's top left). (90 = straight up, + 45 = 135)

so to get the same answer I just said it would be:

```
var dist=Math.sqrt(50^2+50^2);
var degtorad=Math.PI/180;

var x = Math.cos(degtorad * (135+rotation)) * dist;
var y = Math.sin(degtorad * (135+rotation)) * dist;
```

Now x & y will be relative to the origin. If you need more help then be more specific in your question so we can answer better, help us to help you.

quick calculation:

```
rotation=45
135+45 = 180

Math.cos(degtorad * 180)) = -1
Math.sin(degtorad * 180)) = 0;

x = -1 * dist = -70,71067811865475
y = 0 * dist = 0
```

and voila it's like I said for calculating the static in the beginning, I just didn't use any cos / sin for that.. but this works aswell. (-75 works aswell)

Comment: Svennsson thanks for the answer. But what is the variable 'rotation' in your code? Isn't the value 135 already adding 45(my rotation) to 90? So should it maybe be (90+rotation) instead of (135+rotation)? Also will this work an angle like -75deg?

Comment: rotation is how much you've rotated the cube _______

135 is the direction from center to upper left corner.

0 = right _______
45 = upper right _______
90 = up _______
135 = upper left _______

and you said "if I rotate it by 45 degrees", if you do then rotation = 45