# Get elements top and left position after being rotated

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transforms

When I rotate an element via

```
myElem.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
myElem.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
myElem.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
myElem.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
```

I need to get its correct left/top position...

```
myElem.getBoundingClientRect().left
```

...does not deliver the correct x/y positions. As well as f.e. using jQuery...

```
$(myElem).position().left
```

...delivers wrong values.

Here´s an image to show what I mean
[image: rotateddiv]
<sub>(source: [dasprinzip.com](http://www.dasprinzip.com/bitsandpieces/setup.jpg))</sub>

What to do?

Comment: What do you expect it to be, and what do you get instead?

Comment: is this what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795816/obtain-the-actual-left-top-position-of-a-rotated-div?rq=1

Comment: added an image to visualize what´s meant...

Comment: So you want it to deliver the top left corner of the orange box?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a JSFiddle for you which hopefully will give you the ingredients to work everything out:
http://jsfiddle.net/pM54e/2/
The `span` in the Fiddle is to test if the value is correct. Give it the height that's calculated by the formula and see if it matches with the corner of the orange box.

```
var numY = Math.abs(myElem.position().top + sign*( (myElem.outerHeight() / 2) - Math.sin(degree)));
```

This will determine the Y-position of the rotated elements top left corner.
Keep in mind that `(myElem.outerHeight() / 2)` is the `transform-origin` of your element. Default is 50% of the elements height and width. If you change the origin, you have to change that value in the formula.

I don't have much time right now to figure out the x-position and provide a more detailed example but i'll update my answer with more tests, details and the x-value when i do find time tomorrow.

Hope this helps